# I am Making an HR Management Software and want to create different Database for each company

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am Creating software using Flutter and Firebase. Is it possible to create a new project in Firebase for every company that logs in?

Right now every company that is created is stored under one collection but I want to create a new project for every new company so that I can calculate reads, writes, and analytics and can use particular extensions for scaling the project.  [image: Image of Firestore]

We do have our own set of companies that have their own individual set of collections and documents which are to be computed.
We want to charge each and every company as per their usage.

Comment: And you want to do that programatically?

Comment: @AlexMamo Yes I want to create new project programmatically

Comment: do you mean add multiple company name on the company collection?

Answer (score 0):

To create a Firebase project programmatically, you have to use the [Firebase Management API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api/workflow_set-up-and-manage-project).

Comment: Basically I want the number of reads and writes that a company(document) is using so that I can charge accordingly. Is there any way to do so?

Comment: Yes, you can count the number of the document reads, but there is nothing built-in, you have to write code for that. On the other hand, Firebase Management API offers the possibility to create a Firebase project programmatically.

Comment: So can I help you with other information regarding the initial question?